# How to post from blogger to Twitter and FB with blog label as # tag in post content?

Tags: facebook, twitter, if-this-then-that

Currently I'm using IFTTT to perform the following:

If: Any new post on blog
Then: Create a link post on my Facebook fan page

Is it possible to include labels used in blogger with hash tag in my Facebook post?

For example, In my blog post, my labels are "news" and "today".
In my post to Facebook and Twitter, I would want to have something like this:

```
Post Title
Summarized Post Content
Hash tag of labels (#news, #today)
```

Is it possible to achieve this in IFTTT?
If not, any other method can do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Feedburner, there's an option to auto-tweet your posts using Labels as hashtags.

Comment: Oh, I found it in feedburner. Any suggestion for Facebook?